# grails plugin question - unable to resolve class

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

i'm writing my first plugin,

but in test project, can't resolve the class of plugin (src/groovy)

[image]

[image]

Comment: there's something in your CarController, line 3 (according to the error message)

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse and IntelliJ have problems correctly syncing the project. Are you sure it is a Grails resolution problem or an Eclipse/IntelliJ problem? Try to clean & build/run the Grails project on the command line first when having "weird" dependency problems. If this fails it is a genuine dependency problem.

Comment: oh,-1. snapshot is eclipse,but the same error when cmd grails run-app

Comment: Are AbstractController and CarController in different projects?  Is AbstractController in a plugin class and CarController in an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are not properly specifying the dependency between your plugin project and your app.  Have you added a dependency either through the Grails plugin manager or by manually editing the `buildConfig.groovy` file?